# Laravel File-Manager did not show preview picture after uploud

Tags: laravel

Excuse me, could anyone help me please, I have installed `Laravel file manager`, but after I upload picture to `Laravel file manager`, the `Laravel file manager` did not show my uploaded picture, sorry for my English, thank or anyone help

https://ibb.co/9Tz0BhN

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).